# multiple update with jpa

Tags: java, jpa

I need to upgrade a field of several records in bd. How to do this with JPA?. I tried the following but not working:

```
@Override
public String estadoPedido(List<DetallePedido> lista) { 
    int cod;
    String mensage = null;
    for (DetallePedido ped : lista) {
        cod = ped.getIdDetalle();
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        DetallePedido detPed = new DetallePedido();

        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            detPed = em.find(DetallePedido.class, cod);
            detPed.setPedEstado("EN PLAN");
            em.merge(detPed);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            mensage = "detalle seleccionado";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mensage = "Error:/p" + e.getMessage();
        } finally{
            em.close();
        }
    }

    return mensage;
}
```

Comment: What is the error you see? please attach stack traces and errors .

Comment: In addition, please perform the "find" before the transaction begins. No need to have SELECT inside a transaction

Comment: In addition you are opening way too many transactions!

Comment: no error message is displayed, this works for simple updates without the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
@Override
public String estadoPedido(List<DetallePedido> lista) { 
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    //em.getTransaction().begin(); //Consider using Container managed transactions ,
    // if you do remove this line and the line above, and have
    //entity manager injected ! 
    String mensage = null;
    try { 
         for (DetallePedido ped : lista) { 
            detPed.setPedEstado("EN PLAN"); 
            em.merge(detPed); 
         } 
         mensage = "detalle seleccionado"; 
         em.getTransaction().commit; //consider removing this line and use Container managed transactions! 
    } catch (Exception e)  { 
         mensage = "Error:/p" + e.getMessage(); 
    } finally{ 
       em.close(); 
    } 
    return mensage; 
}
```

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, I get the message string, but does not run what is inside the for loop.

Comment: Are you sure lista contains any items? it should definitely run, even if it throws exceptions.
I am fixing the getTransaction part - no need. I highly recommend you use spring or JavaEE to handle transactions for you.

Comment: it is not necessary the commit part in this modification?

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I will make some changes in my application, to test your suggestion again. I mention, this is part of an RPC call, which works if I want to make a single update.

thanks for your time and help. then I write.